# Number of images after image augmentation in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have 100 images, I applied horizontal and vertical augmentation with a probability of 1 using Pytorch function `RandomHorizontalFlip` and `RandomVerticalFlip`. After this would my total number of images will be 300 or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can get 300 images  if you keep the original 100 images then calling and store the return of two function separately, e.g:

```
from torchvision import transforms
import torch

trhf = transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(p=1.)
trvf = transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(p=1.)

imgs = torch.rand(100, 3, 28, 28)
imgs_hf = trhf(imgs)
imgs_vf = trvf(imgs)

all_imgs = torch.cat((imgs, imgs_hf, imgs_vf), 0)
all_imgs.size()
```

Outputs:

```
imgs_hf size: torch.Size([100, 3, 28, 28]), imgs_vf size: torch.Size([100, 3, 28, 28]), all_imgs size: torch.Size([300, 3, 28, 28])
```

But if you using `transforms.Compose` or `torch.nn.Sequential` on those two function then it will only return same size of images (i.e 100)

Comment: yes, i know it will return 100 images, but in backend does the learning take place on 100 images or 300 images, ignore batch size for the sake of ease.

Comment: @TalhaAnwar, Obviously if you using `transforms.Compose` or `torch.nn.Sequential` and follow with the network then is 100, if you process the images first like I show you above and feed those images to network then it is 300, i.e depend on how you create the model

Answer (score 0):

the Above illustration is precise.[to show if you want to increase the dataset size]
but when you are using `transforms.Compose` function it augment images in the runtime and dumps them after the operation. this is because storage redundant data is only a storage overhead.